# Return individual sender of archived mail for a shared mailbox

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have written a macro which pulls the emails from the 'Sent Items' of a particular mailbox in Outlook. I am using .SenderName property to populate senders name in Excel.
The mailbox is shared by a team, and is labeled as 'ResearchHub'.

The macro is working when I pull out mails for recent days.

When I try to draw the archived mails, the .SenderName property pulls out the sender as 'ResearchHub', not the person who sent the mail.

`MailItem.SentOnBehalfOfName` property is pulling Research Hub as the sender and not the individual name.

I tried unarchiving the emails by opening them and copying them in a different folder, yet was unsuccessful in fetching the particular user as sender name.

```
Option Explicit
Sub test()

Dim Result As Object
Dim i As Integer
Dim dstart As Date
Dim dend As Date
Dim lower As String
Dim upper As String
Dim limit As String

dstart = InputBox("Enter Start Date in dd/mmm/yyyy format")
dend = InputBox("Enter End Date in dd/mmm/yyyy format")
lower = "[ReceivedTime] > '" & Format(dstart, "ddddd") & " 12:00 AM" & "'"
upper = "[ReceivedTime] > '" & Format(dend, "ddddd") & " 12:00 AM" & "'"

limit = lower & " AND " & upper

Dim objoutlook As outlook.Application
Dim oStore As outlook.Store
Dim onjNSpace As outlook.Namespace
Dim objFolder As outlook.Folder
Dim oAccount As Account

Set objoutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objNSpace = objoutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

For Each objFolder In objNSpace.Folders

    If objFolder.Name = "Research Hub" Then

        Dim myfolder As outlook.Folder
        Set myfolder = objFolder.Folders("Sent Items")

        Dim objitem As Object
        Dim irow As Integer
        irow = 2
        Set Result = myfolder.Items.Restrict(limit)

        If Result.Couunt > 0 Then

            For i = 1 To Result.Count

                Cells(irow, 1) = objitem.SenderName
                Cells(irow, 2) = objitem.To
                Cells(irow, 3) = objitem.Subject

                irow = irow + 1

            Next i
        End If
    End If
Next

Set objoutlook = Nothing
Set objNSpace = Nothing
Set myfolder = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: @PEH I used MailItem.SentOnBehalfOfName property but I still is pulling Research Hub as the sender and not the individual name

Answer (score 0):

Use the `MailItem.SentOnBehalfOfName` property instead.

Comment: @PEH I used MailItem.SentOnBehalfOfName property but I still is pulling Research Hub as the sender and not the individual name

Comment: @Mathieu Guindon - can you please help me out  here

Comment: can you help me out here...I tried unarchiving the emails by opening them and copying them in a different folder, yet was unsuccessful in fetching out the particular user as sender name

Comment: Take a look at the MAPI properties of the problematic message with OutlookSpy (select the message, click IMessage button). Do you see any properties with the right value?